# MySQL Multi-Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have multiple tables I am trying to grab data from in a single query.  I seem to be close to a solution but can not seem to get the data result I am expecting.

Examples of my tables are as follows (fields have been truncated):

Table c
id
name
abbreviation

Table mr (relationship table tat ties tables c and m together by ID)
id
c.id
m.id

Table m
id

Table cnt
id
c.id

Table cmp
id
cnt.id
active

What I WANT is all fields from C, all fields from M where m.id = c.id, all active (active = 1) id's from CMP that match on cnt.id.

My most recent query (after dozens of iterations) is:

```
SELECT c.id AS id
    , c.name AS name
    , c.abbreviation AS abbr
    , c.active AS active
    , c.last_modified AS last_modified
    , c.modified_by AS modified_by
    , mr.media_id
    , mr.related_object_table
    , mr.related_object_id
    , m.orig_name AS img_name
    , m.unique_name AS img_slug
    , m.file_type AS confed_file_type
    , m.file_size AS file_size
    , COUNT('cmp.id') AS comps
FROM confederations AS c
LEFT JOIN media_relationships AS mr 
ON mr.related_object_id = c.id 
AND mr.related_object_table = 'confederations'
LEFT JOIN media AS m 
ON m.id = mr.media_id
INNER JOIN countries AS cnt
ON cnt.confederations_id = c.id
INNER JOIN competitions AS cmp
ON cmp.countries_id = cnt.id 
AND cmp.active = 1;
```

I am not proficient with Joins.

Basically, the result i am expecting is: For each Confederation (table C) I want that confederations name, abbreviation, active status (active), last modified date, modified by; from the Media Relationship table (table MR) I want the image id associated with that confederation so I can use that id to grab the image name and image slug for the confederations primary image from the Media table (M).

Now I also want the total number of Competitions (table CMP) for a given Confederation. Competitions are stored with a Country ID that is tied to the primary key ID of a country in the Countries Table (table CNT). Each Country in table CNT has a Confederations ID. So to get the total number of Competitions per Confederation I am 'trying' to get all Countries within their respective Confederation by CONFEDERATIONS_ID in table CNT, then foreach confederation I want select all the competitions from table CMP with matching COUNTRIES_ID from the group of country id's for that given confederation.  (At this point i think i am confusing myself with how to get what i want)

Somehow I am getting the CORRECT NUMBER of competitions, but I am getting duplicate Confederations as results. For Example I am getting something similar to this (assume I have 3 different confederations with 2, 1, and 3 competitions respectively):

```
Competitions 1 : name 1 | abbreviation 1 | image 1 | total competitions = 2;
Competitions 1 : name 1 | abbreviation 1 | image 1 | total competitions = 1;
Competitions 1 : name 1 | abbreviation 1 | image 1 | total competitions = 3
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try to put your inner join on top of your left join, and see if it works.

Comment: Should "COUNT('cmp.id')", be "COUNT(cmp.id)"?  Also, what to you want to aggregate by (e.g. GROUP BY)?  I do not understand your last paragraph.

Comment: @grepLines : i get the same result if i place my INNER joins before my LEFT joins

Comment: @Degan - thanks for the edit to make my query clearer, was not sure how to format it like you did. Re: my final paragraph:i have edited my question to try to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, I actually solved this on my own.  I came back to post my answer and see Degan's answer, and though it is written differently than mine I *think* its very close to what I ended up with:

```
SELECT
    cnf.id AS confed_id, cnf.name AS confed_name, cnf.abbreviation AS 
    confed_abbr, cnf.active AS confed_active, cnf.modified_by AS 
    confed_mod_by, cnf.last_modified AS confed_last_mod,
    COUNT(cnt.id) AS total_countries,
    COUNT(cmp.id) AS total_comps,
    mr.media_id, mr.related_object_table, mr.related_object_id, 
    mr.primary_img,
    m.orig_name AS img_name, m.unique_name AS img_slug, m.file_type AS file_type
FROM confederations AS cnf
LEFT JOIN media_relationships AS mr
ON mr.related_object_id = cnf.id AND mr.related_object_table = 'confederations'
LEFT JOIN media AS m
ON m.id = mr.media_id
LEFT JOIN countries AS cnt
ON cnt.confederations_id = cnf.id AND cnt.active = 1
LEFT JOIN competitions AS cmp
ON cmp.countries_id = cnt.id AND cmp.active = 1
GROUP BY cnf.id
```

So farthis seems to be giving me results i can use.  I am not certain if my choice of Left Join for all my joins is in fact giving me everything i need (it SEEMS to be) and whether this will omit/add records once the tables get larger. If anyone can point out a problem in my query and my choice of using Left Join as opposed to a combination of LEFT and INNER JOINs as Degan did, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When aggregating you need to group by.

Perhaps this is close to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT c.id AS id
     , c.name AS name
     , c.abbreviation AS abbr
     , m.orig_name AS img_name
     , SUM('cmp.id') AS comps
FROM confederations AS c
LEFT JOIN media_relationships AS mr 
   ON mr.related_object_id = c.id
   AND mr.related_object_table = 'confederations'
LEFT JOIN media AS m 
   ON m.id = mr.media_id
INNER JOIN countries AS cnt
   ON cnt.confederations_id = c.id
INNER JOIN competitions AS cmp
   ON cmp.countries_id = cnt.id 
   AND cmp.active = 1
GROUP BY  c.id AS id
        , c.name AS name
        , c.abbreviation AS abbr
        , m.orig_name AS img_name
```

Comment: thank you for posting this!  As mentioned in my answer above you posted about an hour before I got to a usable solution throughTrial and Error.  I did use Group By as you can see.  Can you explain why you have redundant calls for certain fields (for example, c.id in both SELECT FROM confederations  and the LEFT JOIN media_relationships)? The way you write your MYSQL is different than what I've seen before.

Comment: Sorry, the redundant select entries in the LEFT JOIN  was a typo from my cutting/pasting.  Sorry for the confusion.  Otherwise, not having your data set, I can only assume that the joins are correct.